# how to select one thing and if the condition is false then select something else

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table called `mytable`:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+
|ID   | ID2 | product   |
+-----+-----+-----------+
|   1 | 1   | product1  |
|   2 | 2   | product1  |
|   3 | 1   | product2  |
|   4 | 4   | product2  |
|   5 | 1   | product3  |
|   6 | 1   | product4  |
|   7 | 4   | product4  |
+-----+-----+-----------+
```

I want to select all products that have `id2 = 4` but if they don't have `id2 = 4` then show `id2 = 1`.

The output should be:

```
id  product
1   product1
4   product2
5   product3
7   product4
```

Could I do something like this in SQL  (I am using mysql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another query using conditional aggregation to select products and the id corresponding to id2=4 or id2=2

```
select coalesce(
      max(case when id2=4 then id end),
      max(case when id2=1 then id end)
    ) id,
    product
from mytable
where id2 in (4,1)
group by product
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47050/1

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use `OR`. It should work in this case, because if you meet the first condition, you're satisfied. If you don't, you'll fall back on the second one. If you still don't meet it, then it won't be included. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product
FROM myTable
WHERE id2 = 4 OR id2 = 1;
```

**EDIT**

This doesn't select the id, but I'm not sure how you want to select the id. What if a product has `id2=4` twice? Which `id` value would you select? If this doesn't solve your entire problem, let me know and I will try to help work out the full solution.

Comment: The whole point of the question is to select the row with `id2 = 4` in preference to `id2 = 1`. Your answer doesn't implement any preference.

Comment: Did you read the edit part of my answer? The same thing applies in a way.

Comment: I did, and it just seems to be saying "I didn't bother selecting the ID, despite that being what you asked for".

Comment: Most likely, it can't have duplicate `id2`, so your question isn't an issue. But even so, the point is still to prefer 4 over 1.

Comment: Well i can see some ambiguity then. It seemed to me that the most important part was getting products that had id2 = 4, and if not then id2 = 1. If they dont need the id column then this is likely enough. If they do i will have to edit this with a preference. Im commenting on mobile so will have to do it later.

Comment: @Barmar the accepted answer really doesn't handle preference, either, so it doesn't seem like that was really what they were looking for after all.

Comment: Yes it does. `COALESCE` returns the first non-null argument. So if there are any rows with `id2 = 4` it returns that ID, otherwise it returns the ID for a row with `id2 = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select *
from mytable
where id2 = 4
union all
select *
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from mytable t2 
                  where t2.product = t.product and t2.id2 = 4) 
      and t.id2 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, product
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, product
       ,case id2 when 4 then 0
                       when 1 then 1
         end as preference
     FROM 
        products) as t
 ORDER BY t.preference
```